# What jurisdiction do Scottish courts have over the Westminster parliament?

Tags: united-kingdom, parliament, scotland, judiciary

What jurisdiction do the Scottish courts have to declare the suspension of the Westminster parliament is illegal? Since the Scots and English legal systems are different, and nobody has suspended the Scottish Parliament, why wasn't the matter taken through the English courts?

Comment: The prorogation is being fought in both the Scottish and English court - the Scottish court because the English court was not in session at the time and an emergency injunction was being sought.

Comment: Note that the jurisdiction is also not an English one - it's a UK one, which is an important distinction

Comment: Why would English courts have precedence over UK matters?

Comment: Incidentally, the _actual act_ that the court concluded was unlawful was that of _advising the Queen_ to prorogue parliament -- and that act took place at a privy council meeting held at Balmoral Castle **in Scotland**.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The United Kingdom has 3 [legal jurisdictions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_United_Kingdom): England and Wales, Northern Ireland, and Scotland.

Citizens are entitled to bring cases in their own jurisdiction, or any other by mutual agreement (particularly for civil cases). In fact, independent cases are being heard in all 3 jurisdictions.

There is a single UK-wide [Supreme Court](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supreme_Court_of_the_United_Kingdom) which acts as the final court of appeal for all jurisdictions (save that which affects EU law).

The UK government is bound by Scots law for its actions in Scotland and has a legal advisor for that purpose, the [Advocate General for Scotland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advocate_General_for_Scotland). These cases are after all to challenge the actions of the executive.

Comment: It might be useful to mention that the Supreme Court only handles cases that started in lower courts; it was never an option to file the proroguing case directly at the Supreme Court level.

Answer (score 17):

The Westminster parliament is the parliament of the United Kingdom.  Scotland is part of the United Kingdom.  (The parliament of Scotland has authority over certain "devolved" matters only.)

Any act of the Westminster parliament or of the UK government affecting Scotland must be lawful under the law of Scotland.  This gives Scotland's courts jurisdiction over those acts.

Because Scotland is part of the UK and is represented in Westminster and is subject to the authority of the Westminster parliament, proroguing the parliament affects Scotland.

> Since the Scots and English legal systems are different, and nobody has suspended the Scottish Parliament, why wasn't the matter taken through the English courts?

The legal systems of Scotland and England are not completely different.  The [Acts of Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acts_of_Union_1707) provided that the various bodies of *law* in Scotland remained in force, and that much of the *judiciary* in Scotland remained in place, but it explicitly did away with Scotland's parliament by providing

> THAT the United Kingdom of Great Britain be Represented by one and the same Parliament to be stiled The Parliament of Great Britain.

In other words, the systems are not entirely separate because they are both subject to the authority of the UK parliament.

As an aside, the parliament in Holyrood is a rather late comer to the scene.  It dates from [changes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Scottish_devolution) made nearly 300 years after the Union of Scotland and England, or just over 20 years ago.  The [Scotland Act 1998](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scotland_Act_1998) specified the matters reserved to the UK parliament in its [Schedule 5](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1998/46/schedule/5).  These include

> The Constitution
>
> 1 The following aspects of the constitution are reserved matters, that is—
>
> (a) the Crown, including succession to the Crown and a regency,
>
> (b) the Union of the Kingdoms of Scotland and England,
>
> (c) the Parliament of the United Kingdom,
>
> ...

So the UK parliament is not something the Scottish parliament can legislate about.  But the Scottish *courts* can indeed consider constitutional matters.  There is no UK-wide system of courts in which such matters could be heard, and the courts of the jurisdiction of England and Wales don't have jurisdiction in Scotland.

Answer (score 9):

Scottish people elect representatives to *both* Westminster *and* Holyrood.

There's news about the group who chose to go to a Scottish court, rather than those who went to an English court, as they were the first to be heard, because the English court wasn't hearing cases that week.

Comment: They chose to go for various different reasons, of which this was one. Note that there are various ongoing court cases

Comment: English constitutional law is actually different to Scottish constitutional law (principally due to precedences set during the Victorian era).

Comment: @GeoffAtkins precedents.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins UK constitutional law is the same in both places.

Comment: @Yakk [Citation needed]

Comment: @GeoffAtkins There is one UK, and one UK constitution, and one supreme court in the UK to interpret it.  Any disagreement with the UK supreme court's interpretation of constitutional law can be overridden.

Comment: @Yakk - Really? And where is that written?

Comment: @GeoffAtkins Are you disputing that "the UK" is a thing?  If so, this is my citation: https://wondermark.com/1k62/

Comment: @Yakk - Are you suggesting that there's no difference between English law and Scots law?

Comment: @GeoffAtkins No, I am suggesting that "Constitutional Reform Act 2005, Part 3, Section 23(1) and s. 23" states there is one supreme UK court, and that court has final say on constitutional matters.

Comment: It's very difficult to find actual references to such things. But the FT (which pretty good on such things) reckons it has found them.
https://www.ft.com/content/12097e7c-d47f-11e9-8367-807ebd53ab77

Comment: @Yakk you seem to have mistakenly assumed that because there's only one Supreme Court there's only one system of law on which it adjudicates. If you continue your reading of the CRA 2005 through to [Section 41](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2005/4/section/41) you will be disabused of that misapprehension.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins no he's suggesting that there is only one law (which is common to English and Scots Law) when it comes to matters of the UK constitution; to suggest otherwise would clearly be absurd. (I do agree with Will that the Supreme Court does not necessarily deal with one system of law though)

Comment: https://twitter.com/davidallengreen/status/1171717055911014400

Comment: @Orangesandlemons "to suggest otherwise would clearly be absurd" - Absurd or not, it appears to be the case; and when has absurdity been a bar to something being the law?  (See the tweets from from David Allen Green's tweets from David Allen Green.)

Comment: @GeoffAtkins again, clearly absurd. I'd take the tweets of a man who uses the word 'contaminated' for the alleged English law view with a _large_ pinch of salt. However, his claims do seem to have some merit, as he tried to play it as an issue of whether 'unconstitutional is unlawful' which could be argued as less absurd (as that principle could predate the actual constitution, which logically can only have one result) If you see the argument Yakk is putting forward is regarding the constitution itself. To be perfectly honest, I think its academic, as it clearly was a political decision

Comment: (to elaborate, political as in teh judges have made a law up from whole cloth because they are anti-constitution as it exists, not political as anti-brexit, although that may well be the case)

Comment: note that if this ruling by the Scottish government is to be considered binding, it follows that all the generally used delaying tactics used including to starve bills etc of time should become 'unlawful'. A lot of people have rightly been going on about the 'rule of law' but that includes the judges not legislating.

Comment: David Allen Green is widely respected. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Allen_Green

Comment: @GeoffAtkins I'm not saying he's not widely respected -  I both concede he may have a point after the 'constitutional' question, and also highlighted that he is biased in that very thread. Another point about the thread, which undermines it somewhat, is he plays it as Scottish vs English, while conveniently ignoring the fact a scottish Judge had already ruled like the English Court (this was appeal) https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-scotland-scotland-politics-49568760. Another thing is the thread was made _after the fact_ . He may have made this point before, but I'm unaware of that.

Answer (score 2):

> What jurisdiction do the Scottish courts have to declare the
>   suspension of the Westminster parliament is illegal?

The Westminster Parliament is the parliament for all four nations of the United Kingdom. Therefore it MUST run legally as per the laws of all four nations. Regardless of the English and Wales ruling, if it is illegal in part of the United Kingdom, then it is illegal, full stop.

> why wasn't the matter taken through the English courts?

It was. As it is a matter for all the nations of the union, it is currently being persued independently in each nation and at a UK level through the Supreme Court.

Comment: You should support your conclusions with some references.

Comment: I thought it was because English courts aren't sitting until the 1st of October. They are basically still on holiday.

Comment: @Lieuwe The English Courts have already seen a challenge separately.  On the 6th September, they ruled that this was a Political Matter (and thus does not fall within scope of the Courts' remit), so dismissed the case.  Incidentally, this was also the result of the *first* attempt to challenge it in Scotland too, **and** the result of an attempt to challenge the concept of "No-Deal Brexit" as "unlawful" in the Northern-Irish courts.  But really - they can't actually challenge the prorogation, just the *advice* given to the Queen.  Even if the challenge is successful, she can just say "nope".